# Different position image between Xcode 4 and 5

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ios6, ios7

I'm new with iPhone developing and I have many problem about the transition to iOS 7!

[Example screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7M8jw.png)

Why is the position of the image different?

Comment: The one on the left has a navigation bar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

iOS 7 has introduced over 1500 new APIs... It is very unlikely that you will be able to directly transfer your apps between the OS's - if it was the same then there would be little point in Apple putting the work in to a new OS.

In the example that you have given, iOS7 uses a margin from the top of the screen, as opposed to the bottom of the top toolbar.

This [article](http://thinkmobile.appcelerator.com/blog/bid/313119/An-Enterprise-Strategy-for-iOS-7-Migration?mkt_tok=3RkMMJWWfF9wsRojv67PZKXonjHpfsX56uUsW6CwhIkz2EFye%2bLIHETpodcMT8tlN6%2bTFAwTG5toziV8R7bGKs1u0t8QUxbj) helped me work out how to handle the migration.